# MySql/MariaDB: Using Indexes in queries "directly"?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I wonder if there is a possibility in MySql/MariaDB to make use of an index in a query directly. Suppose we have a simple unsorted table with timestamp/value-pairs:

```
CREATE TABLE simple (timestamp DATETIME, val INT);
```

By adding an index for the timestamp:

```
ALTER TABLE simple ADD INDEX ind_ts (timestamp);
```

we have a "fast access" to a kind of sort order of the timestamps.

Let's define a query that delivers the difference of values of consecutive values:

```
SELECT 
    c.timestamp AS currenttimestamp,
    COALESCE(b.timestamp,'0000-00-00 00:00:00') AS timestampbefore,
    c.val - COALESCE(b.val,0) AS difference
FROM simple c, 
simple b 
WHERE b.timestamp = (SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM simple h WHERE h.timestamp < c.timestamp)
```

It is obvious that this query is circumstantial and expensive. A more convient way would be adding a column myindex to the table:

```
 ALTER TABLE simple ADD COLUMN (myindex INT) AFTER timestamp;
```

and fill the new column with the chronical order of timestamp (e.g. by some php-code)

The new query would be simpler and less expensive:

```
SELECT 
    c.timestamp AS currenttimestamp,
    COALESCE(b.timestamp,'0000-00-00 00:00:00') AS timestampbefore,
    c.val - COALESCE(b.val,0) AS difference
FROM simple c
LEFT JOIN simple b ON c.myindex = b.myindex+1
```

The new column myindex is somehow similar to the database's table index ind_ts. (Why) is there no MySql construct to use ind_ts instead of myindex?

Comment: Your query could be better expressed with [LEAD](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/lead/) or LAG window functions. With some luck the optimizer is aware of those and can use the index effectively - though you might need both columns in the index (not familiar with Maria/MySQL).

Comment: @Mat, thanks, I didn't know those windows functions. Performance seems to be weak on MariaDB though, but the query is much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL 8.0 or MariaDB 10.2 (or later), `LEAD()` and `LAG()` provide a simple way to see the row before or after.

If you are using an older version, then do a "self join".  That is, `JOIN` the table to itself.  Then line up the two "tables" offset by one.  This may require generating a temp table with a fresh `AUTO_INCREMENT` to provide an easy way to do the offset.  This may be slightly better than your idea about "myindex".

```
CREATE TABLE new_table (
    myindex INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY(myindex))
  SELECT * FROM simple;
```

Then

```
SELECT a.ts - b.ts AS diff   -- (or whatever the math is)
    FROM new_table AS a
    JOIN new_table AS b  ON a.myindex = b.myindex - 1
```

(This does not take care of the first and last rows of the table.)

Note:  You cannot use a `TEMPORARY TABLE` since such cannot be `JOINed` to itself.